# Show popup one time

Tags: javascript, cookies, popup, squarespace

I have popup that appears when you go to my site - it's a warning label. I only want it to appear on the first visit and not again. Currently every time I click refresh or go back to the homepage it appears.

Here is the JavaScript code (As soon as someone clicks the 'Warning Button Enter'):

```
<script>
"use strict"
warning_popup();

function warning_popup() {
    addEventListener('load', start);

    function start() {
        // popup block background
        var bkg = document.createElement("div");
        bkg.id = "warning-background";
        document.body.insertBefore(bkg, document.body.firstChild);

        // popup window
        var box = document.createElement("div");
        box.id = "warning-window";
        document.getElementById("warning-background").appendChild(box);

        // warning title
        var title = document.createElement("div");
        title.id = "warning-title";
        title.className = "page-title-wrapper page-title";
        title.innerHTML = "<h1>Binge Eating Disorder<\h1>";
        document.getElementById("warning-window").appendChild(title);

        // warning description
        var desc = document.createElement("div");
        desc.id = "warning-desc";
        desc.className = "page-desc";
        desc.innerHTML = "<p>Binge Eating Disorder is disease that I take very seriously.<p>";
        document.getElementById("warning-window").appendChild(desc);

        // warning button enter
        var enter = document.createElement("div");
        enter.id = "warning-enter";
        enter.className = "page-desc";
        enter.innerHTML = "<p>View</p>";
        document.getElementById("warning-window").appendChild(enter);


        // warning button back
        //var back = document.createElement("div");
        //back.id = "warning-back";
        // back.className = "page-desc";
        // back.innerHTML = "<p>Take Me Back</p>";
        // document.getElementById("warning-window").appendChild(back);

        // listens for button clicks
        document.querySelector("#warning-enter").addEventListener("click", function() {
            document.querySelector("#warning-background").style.visibility = "hidden";
        });
        document.querySelector("#warning-back").addEventListener("click", function() {
            window.history.back();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: the solution is simple just set a javascript cookie with an expiry date one year from now and check everytime the page loads. If that cookie is present then dont run the show_popup function

Answer (score 0):

I think `localStorage` can solve your problem. Consider this example:

```
window.onload = init;

function init() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('first_time') === "undefined" || localStorage.getItem('first_time') === null) {
    // Set the storage key and show the warning—but only this one time
    localStorage.setItem('first_time', true);
    showWarning();
  }
}

function showWarning() {
  console.log("Showing warning...");
}
```

Loading this code will only fire the `showWarning` function one time.

https://jsfiddle.net/ez2qqpbx/